# How to debug why a form can not obtain focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, modal-dialog

Using Visual Studio 2019, with an old C# Winforms .NET 4.6.2 application: I have a situation where my main form is acting as if it is being blocked by a modal:

- Makes a beeping sound and flashes when clicking anywhere
- Will not accept focus
- Timer and serial communication Events are still triggering
- No grey screen overlay, or message about the application ever becoming unresponsive

However, I can see no modal form, and using Application.OpenForms doesn't show any of the modals that I have created and have closed a few seconds previously.

I can successfully attach and debug remotely, that is how I know the timer ticks are still firing.

How / Where can I place a breakpoint to troubleshoot why a form will not receive focus / denies click events / thinks it is being blocked by a modal of some kind?

It is too difficult to create a minimal example because the backgroundWorker and showDialog code all seems to work properly in other locations, but the gist of what is happening looks like:

```
Application.Run (new FormA)
...
FormA.showDialog(new FormB)
...
FormB.showDialog(new FormC)
...
FormC.timer_tick() { ...still running... }
FormC.onReceive_data() { ...still running... }
FormC.button_click(){
  ...
  showDialog()
  ...
  showDialog()
  ...
  important.showDialog() { backgroundWorker...database stuff }
  ...
  showDialog()
  ...  
}
(known completion : back to FormC event-loop)
```

It always gets to "known completion" just fine, important.showDialog() seems to work fine, pops up an animating dialog with no buttons, auto closes when backgroundWorker completes, closes itself and moves on to the next dialogs or exits button click fine.
But once back in FormC-Event-loop, the form will not receive any input, as if it is still blocked by some modal somewhere...

If I change to important.show() FormC will not have a problem, but now there is code in the click event running before database activity is finished...

I am more interested in debugging technique in this case as to how I can figure out what windows is doing as I try to click on FormC. What kind of debugging module symbols need to be loaded? Where can I breakpoint to see windows deciding whether a form can receive focus/input?

Comment: Modal Dialogs are just windows called via `showDialog()` rather then `Show()`. With that many show dialogs, I doubt god would be able to keep straight what is happening when. Why do you have dozens of modal dialogs in yoru code?

Comment: if you press Esc or Alt-F4 when your form is refusing to focus, does it come alive again? If you press Alt-Space where does the menu appear? Are you using TopMost=true or ShowInTaskbar=false for any of your windows?

Comment: When a Form is shown with ShowDialog, all other forms are disabled. Your description makes me suspect that something has gone wonky with the re-enabling mechanism.  You could try setting FormC.Enabled property first to false and then back to true at the end of the button click handler to force a call to the API method  EnableWindow with a true argument to see if this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"something has gone wonky with the re-enabling mechanism" made me go through with a fine tooth comb and check how the dialog is being closed off, and I found the original problem:

FormC starts a backgroundWorker and then waits on important.showDialog()

Inside the RunWorkerCompleted() or a timer_tick : "important" was FormC.BeginInvoke() .closed() and .disposed() . But apparently the .dispose() can (but not always) happen on the wrong thread or at the wrong time and then the parent form can never be enabled again. .close() and nulling the formDialog reference allows the parent to get re-Enabled.

Out of interest, I am still wondering how you would go about debugging such a situation?